# Given the polynomial $(x-1)(x-8)(x-31)-1$, how do you conclude that its roots are irrational?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Example $(x-1)(x-8)(x-31)-1$. Just by looking at this polynomial how do you conclude that the roots are irrational?

Comment: Are you familiar with Rational Roots Theorem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any rational root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients is an integer. And the product $(x-1)(x-8)(x-31)$ of three integers can equal $1$ only if all three terms are $\pm 1$. This is clearly not possible, so there are no rational roots.

Comment: Oh ! that was neat... "Any rational root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients is an integer" is obvious using the Rational Roots Theorem. Thanks !